# Performance hit of enabling rewind on all HTTP requests in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am converting a large ASP.NET application to an ASP.NET core application, and I have come across several situations in which we cannot read `Request.Body` stream because it was already read by the time we wanted to read it. Now I realize it would be best to fix these little races but in the interest of getting this moving forward, I've temporarily added the following middleware:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            context.Request.EnableRewind();
            await next.Invoke();
        });
```

What is the performance impact of enable rewind on all the HTTP requests - and was this previously the behavior in ASP.NET anyway?

Comment: What do you think happens when you buffer the whole input stream into the memory? Network streams can only be read once, which make sense since you send data and its read. No way to rewind. To rewind, you have two option: read it into memory or write it to the file system so you can rewind. Think the rest for yourself about performance and efficiency of the whole thing :)

Comment: I guess if the requests don't live that long and you have sufficient memory, it's not so bad is it? And wasn't this the default behavior in ASP.NET (rewinds were enabled by default, so performance shouldn't be any "worse" than before all things being equal)

Comment: Well, imagine 100 requests with a 100 MB file sent to your actions :P Its not an big issue with small requests and if swaps to filesystem you can have heavily degraded I/O performance in high traffic scenarios (or simply when someone DDoS your website). Just look at the sources: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/BufferingHelper.cs & https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/FileBufferingReadStream.cs